# Fastest way to share files between two Windows PC (through WAN)

Tags: windows, file-sharing, file-transfer

What I used back then is **Cygwin with SSH** installed. And then I connected with `FileZilla` or `WinSCP`.

However, this could not copy some of the files, and it is a bit of a hassle to set it up. (And keep updated, since the openSSH-server will be out in the wild with the port open and all.)

FTP is not a solution either, since some of the accented letters will end up at getting not copied at all, or they arrive broken.

What is **most** hassle-free, easiest way to share files between two Windows based PCs?
(TeamViewer would be an easy one, but it is too slow. About 130kbps. RDP is faster, about 350kbps. But they are still **really slow**.)

Host: **XP and above**
Guest: Win x86 (any kind of binary, app which runs under Windows)

Comment: Which versions of Windows specifically ?

Comment: @Karolos - Will edit the question. But basically any Windows XP and above.

Comment: Dropbox? Subversion?
Some sort of NAS?

Answer (score 2):

I find the simplest solution to this is to use [LogMeIn Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/default.aspx). Set up a personal VPN (takes less than 5 minutes on each machine) and then you can share across LAN/WAN/Internet as easily as if the remote system were a local disk (with some speed penalty depending on the distance. Hamachi is free for personal use and I find its performance pretty good (though I have not clocked it).

If your goal is to keep two sets of files in sync between two computers - try [AeroFS](http://www.aerofs.com/). It will keep the files in sync all the time so you don't have to proactively copy at any time - so speed is less of an issue. AeroFS (at this writing) is still in beta so you need an invite. You can sign up in the queue for one at their site. Or you can see if there are any left [here](http://www.pcworld.com/downloads/file/fid,201836-order,4/description.html) (that's where I got mine).

Hope that helps,
Yosh

Comment: Indeed, I used this to share files between friends and myself using our various dedicated servers on Debian. Hamachi is multiplatform, too!